Vite crash ( does not provide an export named 'default' )
I m running React js project with default vite configuration,
current working directory is:
\components\marketing

Hero.jsx
About.jsx
Moreinfo.jsx
Cards.jsx

All those individual components im exporting from index.jsx.
eg: export { default as Hero } from './Hero'
export { default as About } from './About';
Suddenly vite crashes with the following error message:
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/components/ContactUs/Cards.jsx?t=1714559296929' does not provide an export named 'default' (at AboutUs.jsx:2:8)

Once app crashes and I restart vite everything is working fine, sometimes it happens again.

Why is the default as Hero needed? I think that looks wrong. Should be  export { Card, About, Other component }

Is AboutUs looking in the right place? You say you're exporting Cards from the marketing folder (using your barrel file) but AboutUs is looking for Cards in a ContactUs folder.

Are you exporting default inside Hero, About, etc? export default ...?
